# .html() jQuery doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, post

If you choose `Men` then only the child options for `Men` should show.

My footer.php:

```
</div>
<footer class="text-center" id="footer">&copy;Copyright 2015-2016 Shantaus botuquo</footer>
<script>
    function get_child_options(){
        var parentID=jQuery('#parent').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/admin/parsers/child_categories.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {parentID : parentID},
            succes: function(data){
                jQuery('#child').html(data);
            },
            error:function(){alert("Something gone wrong")},
        })
    }
    jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
</script>
```

My child_categories.php:

```
</div>
<footer class="text-center" id="footer">&copy;Copyright 2015-2016 Shantaus botuquo</footer>
<script>
    function get_child_options(){
        var parentID=jQuery('#parent').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/admin/parsers/child_categories.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {parentID : parentID},
            succes: function(data){
                jQuery('#child').html(data);
            },
            error:function(){alert("Something gone wrong")},
        })
    }
    jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
</script>
```

The `<option>` should come back to the page to here:

```
div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="child">Child Category*:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="child" id="child">                   
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: one the console i can see data https://i.gyazo.com/7afb0df6702b4c419cfad7a6e3848cb5.png

Comment: Did you spell the word `success` correctly in your code

Comment: xD YES I DID lol thanks m8 shitty faults